# express js: port running but not able to kill port

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

when i try to run nodemonindex.js  i get this error i have pm2 running but my localhost/5002 gives

```
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
Listening on 5002
events.js:377
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5002
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1331:16)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1379:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1465:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/vivek/mycodes/ask-backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vivek/mycodes/ask-backend/index.js:19:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1358:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 5002
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

i tryed `pm2 kill`   `killall node`  still port doesnot die this happed after i pulled my code from github and running on a new machine i dont know whethere the db is the reson for this error

index.js

```
var moment = require("moment");
var express = require("express");
var ObjectId = require("mongodb").ObjectID;
const { ExploreTrendRequest } = require("g-trends");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var app = express();

// if (process.env.NODE_ENV == "production") {
//   app.use(express.static("portfolio/build"));
//   const path = require("path");
//   app.get("*", (req, res) => {
//     res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "portfolio", "build", "index.html"));
//   });
// }
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5002;

express().listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5002);
const multer = require("multer");
const upload = multer();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(express.json());
var MongoClient = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
var id = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

//Create a database named "mydb":    sudo service mongod start
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";

MongoClient.connect(url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;

  var mydb = db.db(mydb);
  var created = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");

  // mydb.createCollection("questions", function (err, data) {
  // if (err) throw err;
  // var question = {
  //   question: "the first question",
  //   time: created,
  // };
  // mydb.collection("questions").insertOne(question, function (err, data) {
  //   if (err) throw err;
  //   console.log("Data created!");

  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    // Website you wish to allow to connect
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000");

    // Request methods you wish to allow
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
    );

    // Request headers you wish to allow
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "X-Requested-With,content-type"
    );

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);

    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
  });
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.post("/questionpost", function (req, res) {
    let formData = req.body;
    // let bodyJson = JSON.parse(formData);
    console.log(formData);

    mydb.collection("questions").insertOne(formData, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ error: "Ann error has occured" });
      } else {
        res.send(result.ops[0]);
      }
    });
  });

  app.post("/answerpost", function (req, res) {
    let formData = req.body;
    // let bodyJson = JSON.parse(formData);
    // console.log(formData);

    mydb.collection("answers").insertOne(formData, (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        res.send({ error: "Ann error has occured" });
      } else {
        res.send(result.ops[0]);
      }
    });
  });

  app.get("/answersapi/:gotid", function (req, res) {
    let id = req.params.gotid;
    console.log(id);
    mydb
      .collection("answers")
      .find({ question_id: id })
      .toArray(function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw error;
        res.send(data);
      });
  });

  // mydb
  //   .collection("questions")
  //   .insertOne(formData)
  //   .toArray(function (err, res) {
  //     if (err) throw err;
  //     console.log("1 document inserted");
  //   });
  // res.send(res);

  // app.post("/questionpost", jsonParser, function (req, res) {
  //   let data = req;
  //   console.log(data);
  // });

  app.get("/questapi", function (req, res) {
    console.log("apicalled");

    mydb
      .collection("questions")
      .find({})
      .toArray(function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw error;
        res.send(data);
      });
  });

  //http://localhost:5002/answerpost
  // increment;

  app.post("/increment", function (req, res) {
    let id = req.body;
    var correctcount = id.correctcount + 1;
    //var ansid = id.Answer_id;
    var realid = ObjectId(id.Answer_id);
    console.log(correctcount);

    // var myquery = { address: "Valley 345" };
    // var newvalues = { $set: { name: "Mickey", address: "Canyon 123" } };
    // dbo
    //   .collection("customers")
    //   .updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function (err, res) {
    //     if (err) throw err;
    //     console.log("1 document updated");
    //     db.close();
    //   });

    mydb
      .collection("answers")
      .updateOne(
        { _id: realid },
        { $set: { correctcount: correctcount } },
        function (err, data) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("1 document updated");
          res.send(data);
        }
      );
  });

  app.post("/decrementer", function (req, res) {
    let id = req.body;
    var wrongcount = id.wrongcount - 1;
    //var ansid = id.Answer_id;
    var realid = ObjectId(id.Answer_id);
    console.log(wrongcount);

    // var myquery = { address: "Valley 345" };
    // var newvalues = { $set: { name: "Mickey", address: "Canyon 123" } };
    // dbo
    //   .collection("customers")
    //   .updateOne(myquery, newvalues, function (err, res) {
    //     if (err) throw err;
    //     console.log("1 document updated");
    //     db.close();
    //   });

    mydb
      .collection("answers")
      .updateOne(
        { _id: realid },
        { $set: { wrongcount: wrongcount } },
        function (err, data) {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log("1 document updated");
          res.send(data);
        }
      );
  });

  app.get("/questone/:gotid", function (req, res) {
    let id = req.params.gotid;
    // /console.log(id);
    mydb
      .collection("questions")
      .find({ _id: ObjectId(id) })
      .toArray(function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw error;
        //console.log(data);
        res.send(data);
      });
  });

  //trend api call

  app.post("/trend", function () {
    const explorer = new ExploreTrendRequest();
    console.log("api calling 1");
    explorer
      .addKeyword("Dream about snakes")
      .compare("Dream about falling")
      .download()
      .then((csv) => {
        console.log(
          "[✔] Done, take a look at your beautiful CSV formatted data!"
        );
        console.log(csv);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("[!] Failed fetching csv data due to an error", error);
      });
  });
});
```

i have posted my index.js here so that u can reffer what the error is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it works on another computer, this is probably not a problem with your app. The port is simply already in use by another process. Possibly a whole another application. What you want to do is to

1. Identify the process that is already using the port
2. kill it

If you use Mac, you do that by first running `sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN`. This will list all processes that are listening on any port. Find the one running on port 5002 (since this is the one you're using here). The second column in the table that lsof produced is a process number. Now you can run `kill -9 <process number>`. After that your application should work

Comment: when i try 5003 it also says the same error

Comment: what does `sudo lsof -i -P | grep LISTEN` print? What OS are you running? Windows? Linux? MacOS? How do you start your application?

Comment: i am using ubuntu 18.4 now i build this app on ubuntu 20..4

Comment: systemd-r   533 systemd-resolve   13u  IPv4  24693      0t0  TCP localhost:53 (LISTEN)
cupsd       790            root    6u  IPv6  27989      0t0  TCP ip6-localhost:631 (LISTEN)
cupsd       790            root    7u  IPv4  27990      0t0  TCP localhost:631 (LISTEN)
node      15294           vivek   23u  IPv4 112428      0t0  TCP *:3000 (LISTEN)
mongod    15760         mongodb   12u  IPv4 118603      0t0  TCP localhost:27017 (LISTEN)

Comment: nodemon index.js

Comment: oh man. Look at the top of your file. You first say `express().listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${PORT}`));`. That listens on port 5002. And then right in the next line you write `app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5002);` your app explicitly wants to start the server twice on the same port

Comment: you probably didn't mean to write that first line: `express().listen(PORT, () => console.log(Listening on ${PORT}));` delete it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237746/discussion-between-meenu-ks-and-kamil-janowski).